# Load data infile slow executing from node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, bash

I'm trying to insert more than 600,000 rows in a table from my script written in node js using the next query.

```
var sql =   " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/insertFile18.csv'" + 
                    " INTO TABLE `pricing_leasing`"  +  
                    " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '+-'";
```

The problem is that it never finishes (I waited for 1 hour over lunch), neither does it give an error. 
I executed directly in the bash and it was very fast, less than one minute.
Then I decided to write a little script in nodejs which doesn't do anything else except execute the script and it finishes in 2 minutes which is ok.

My question is why if I just execute the query in bash or in it's own node js script does it work fine, but if I have more stuff going on before (other queries on different tables & file operations) it became slow.

**UPDATE**

```
function uploadFile() {

var deferred    = GLOBAL.q.defer(),
    strFileName = "/tmp/insertFile" + GLOBAL.company.id + ".csv",
    cb = function ( err ) {
        //fs.unlinkSync( strFileName );
        if ( err ) {
            console.log( err ); 
            GLOBAL.objRstOfInsert['success'] = false;
        } else {
            // Update return structure with success message
            GLOBAL.objRstOfInsert['success'] = true;
        }
        console.log("finished uploads");
        deferred.resolve();
    };

    var lstInsertPricingColumns = '(`sourcecompany_id`,'+
                            '`company_id`,'+
                            '`price`,`active`,`row_hash`)';

    var sql =   " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + strFileName + "'" + 
                " INTO TABLE " + GLOBAL.company.tableInsert +   
                " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '+-'"+ 
                lstInsertPricingColumns;

    GLOBAL.db['rates'].query( sql, cb );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: we need you to show us the full nodejs code in order to help you. Thanks

Comment: The full script is huge, with a lot of files, I have this script in a function that when is call only do this. If I comment this function everything work fine.

But there is a wear behavior, depending in which server I execute the script it run faster than other. Could be some problem with any configuration files?

Comment: Well show us the part of the script which executes this sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the cloud server have less ram than my local. Then I guess the file was too big. I fixed splitting in multiples smaller files to do the load data and now work fine.

Thanks.